# PHP URL processing

Tags: php

Someone may saw the similar question like this,but I can't find the complete resolution about this.
now here has a link `www.example.com/test/index.php`, if I add an slash to the end, like `www.example.com/test/index.php/`,it would get

> redirected you too many times

so I use this code to filter the url:

```
if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'] != "/" && preg_match('{/$}',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI'])) {
    header ('Location: '.preg_replace('{/$}', '', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']));
    exit();
}
```

it would turn `index.php/` into `index.php`

but now if I just go `www.example.com/test/` it would get

> redirected you too many times.

so now my question is, how can I let them both work?

P.S. My server can't use .htacess

Comment: what is in the `.htaccess` file?

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix I can't use .htacess

Comment: Well I think something is rewriting your urls, is it `IIS` server, Windows in other words?  They have a rewriting deal too but it's been an age sense I even thought about that.

Comment: @ArtisticPhoenix my server is nginx,use Ubuntu

Comment: Are you sure it works fine without the slash? Like `https://example.com/index.php` shows no error?

Comment: Yes,no any error @DevashishJaiswal

Comment: This link might help: https://serverfault.com/questions/650699/getting-too-many-redirects-error-with-nginx-rewrite-rule

Comment: Uh...so I can't use php to fix it? @DevashishJaiswal